# npm throws this error '"**/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am new to angular and I am trying to build a palteform with highcharts and I get this error :

> ERROR in node_modules/highcharts-angular/lib/highcharts-chart.component.d.ts(22,25): error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/HP/Desktop/PFE/Nouveau dossier 3/dashboard/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.
>   node_modules/highcharts-angular/lib/highcharts-chart.component.d.ts(23,18): error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta' requires 6 type argument(s).
>
> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
>   i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem that occurs after upgrading from angular 8 to 9, the possible solution is to delete your `node_modules` and run `npm install` again.

Original thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59741546/12285185

If this won't help please recreate your config in the online editor like stackblitz so I can check why it is not working, or what could be done.