# The target entry-point "@ngrx/store" has missing dependencies: - @angular/core

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

After installing ngrx store I get this error, does anybody know why?

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\NgRxExample\ngrx-applications>ng s -o

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.04 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 697 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 9.73 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 340 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-09-11T05:00:32.637Z - Hash: 7a41446eaa7b76a1e566 - Time: 2949ms
```

**ERROR in The target entry-point "@ngrx/store" has missing dependencies:
- @angular/core**

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Comment: All you did was install the package? You did not use it?

Comment: I want to use it, but before that, I wanted to compile and see if everything works, but not anymore

Comment: Probably you have a peer dependency conflict.

Comment: how can I resolve that?

Comment: Make sure that the version of ngrx you're using is compatible with the same version of angular your app is using.

Comment: No change, the error remains

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix here: [Ng serve throwing @angular/core/core has no exported member 'eeFactoryDef'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078033/ng-serve-throwing-angular-core-core-has-no-exported-member-eefactorydef)

```
In myApp's tsconfig.json file, made the following entry under compilerOptions

    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"]
    },
```