# has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'

Tags: angular

I am facing problem in angular 8 version.

ERROR in node_modules/ng-click-outside/lib_commonjs/click-outside.directive.d.ts(34,21): error TS2694: Namespace '"/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ng serve throwing @angular/core/core has no exported member 'eeFactoryDef'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078033/ng-serve-throwing-angular-core-core-has-no-exported-member-eefactorydef)

Answer (score -1):

Delete node modules folder and run command npm install again. Do a fresh setup.

Comment: it's not working. I think it's problem of angular version for "ng-click-outside" module.